# Rust flo_draw graphics library is not building

Tags: rust, graphics

The issue I'm having are regarding a copy-pasted flo_draw example program. I am using vscode and the rust-anylizer extension. It tells me `failed to run build scripts, check server logs for more information` apon copying the code in. I don't know how to check these or what they are. Using `cargo run` from the terminal yields no better results.

I tried to copy in the code below:

```
// src.main.rs
use flo_draw::*;
use flo_draw::canvas::*;

fn main() {
with_2d_graphics(|| {
let canvas = create_canvas_window("Hello, world");
});
}
```

```
$ cargo run
Compiling futures v0.3.25
Compiling semver v0.11.0
Compiling flo_render_gl_offscreen v0.3.0
Compiling allsorts v0.5.1
Compiling winit v0.24.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `flo_render_gl_offscreen v0.3.0`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/<path to program>/target/debug/build/flo_render_gl_offscreen-9d539a79f1cb257c/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
\--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libclang: "couldn't find any valid shared libraries matching: \['libclang.so', 'libclang-*.so', 'libclang.so.*', 'libclang-*.so.*'\], set the `LIBCLANG_PATH` environment variable to a path where one of these files can be found (invalid: \[\])"', /<path to home>/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bindgen-0.54.0/src/lib.rs:1959:31
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Answer (score 0):

`flo_draw`, or, more specifically, one of its dependencies, [links to the external C library](https://github.com/Logicalshift/flo_draw/blob/v0.4/render_gl_offscreen/build.rs#L15-L21) and therefore have to generate the matching API. This is done using `bindgen`, which [requires `clang` to be installed](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/requirements.html) in your system.

Installation instructions from the linked page:

> Debian-based Linuxes
>
> ```
> # apt install llvm-dev libclang-dev clang
> ```
>
> Ubuntu 18.04 provides the necessary packages directly.
>
> Arch
>
> ```
> # pacman -S clang
> ```
>
> Fedora
>
> ```
> # dnf install clang-devel
> ```